# Why are mercurial log results hidden behind --removed when file wasn't removed?

Tags: mercurial

I've got a strange situation with Mercurial where some commits don't show up in `hg log` results or TortoiseHG file history. Here are some simplified details.

At the command line, if I type `hg log file.txt` I get, say, 8 commits showing up. The recent changes to that file on this branch don't show up. The changes on this branch are the result of a few squashed commit ranges from another branch, but no file removals.

If I type `hg log --removed file.txt` instead, all the commits I expect to see are there.

For the record, typing `hg log -r "removes(file.txt)"` shows nothing, not surprising since the file has never been removed.

My colleague sees the same issue when looking at their history. The changes are public in a shared repository.

Does anyone have any clues as to what would cause this?

Full disclosure: the changes ported from the other branch were compressed on the original branch, popped off into the patch queue and reapplied onto the new branch. I didn't think this would matter. Also, probably unrelated, these same commits were ported to a different branch via grafting. Interestingly, the graft commits DO show up in the commit log without `--removed`, though the original commits don't!

- Mercurial 3.9.2.
- TortoiseHg 4.6.1.
- Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation(`hg log --help`) says that:

`For performance reasons, 'hg log FILE' may omit duplicate changes made
on branches and will not show removals or mode changes. To see all such
changes, use the --removed switch.`

As your changes on the files are the results of squashed commits (how did you squashed them by the way?), it is possible that they have been omitted by this heuristic.

Comment: Thanks, maybe that explains it. The squashes were done with TortoiseHG's "Compress History".